# how to access mySQL database from android without php

Tags: android, mysql

I have a database located in online server and i want to access the data inside it without using php scripts from my android application. The requested data depends on what customer wants. so the data is not constant. any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Expose the database via some Web service, written in a language other than PHP

Step #2: Consume the Web service in your Android app

Answer (score 0):

You need a minimum "server side" to deal with the DB. You can write it in the language that you prefer... in PHP,Java Python or whatever